# Google Cloud Run can only handle 100 request maximum concurrently

Tags: docker, codeigniter, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

So, my development team was trying to migrate from GCE to GCR and we have succeeded in deploying the Cloud Run service and The CI/CD using github actions. But we encountered an issue which is the amount of request the Cloud Run service can handle is not more than 100 request concurrently.
So our base framework for the app is php/codeigniter and the web server we are using is apache2 webserver, along with sql server as our database that we already included in our dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4.22-apache
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2
RUN apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
RUN apt-get install zlib1g-dev
RUN apt-get install libpng-dev -y
RUN docker-php-ext-install curl
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install wget
RUN wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.28-10+deb10u1_amd64.deb

RUN dpkg -i multiarch-support_2.28-10+deb10u1_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get install -y libodbc1
RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
RUN pecl install sqlsrv
RUN pecl install pdo_sqlsrv 
RUN echo "extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files" | sed -e "s|.:\s||"`/30-pdo_sqlsrv.ini
RUN echo "extension=sqlsrv.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files" | sed -e "s|.:\s||"`/30-sqlsrv.ini

RUN rm multiarch-support_2.28-10+deb10u1_amd64.deb
# RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install mssql-tools
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
COPY openssl.cnf /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN  /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and this is the dockerfile that we used

```
FROM jamesjones/test-base:latest
USER root
COPY . /var/www/html
RUN cd /var/www/html
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

COPY v1/application/config/config.prod.php /var/www/html/v1/application/config/config.php
COPY v1/application/config/database.prod.php /var/www/html/v1/application/config/database.php
COPY v1/application/config/routes.prod.php /var/www/html/v1/application/config/routes.php
COPY v2/application/config/config.prod.php /var/www/html/v2/application/config/config.php
COPY v2/application/config/database.prod.php /var/www/html/v2/application/config/database.php
COPY v2/application/config/routes.prod.php /var/www/html/v2/application/config/routes.php
COPY .htaccess.prod /var/www/html/.htaccess

VOLUME /var/www/html
```

i have tried this steps and it appears that the problem still persist
`https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/3-ways-optimize-cloud-run-response-times`

this is our cloud run specification
[image: gcr-spec]

i have also tried to increase the minimum number of instance in autoscaling to 10 but there seems to be no difference.

are there any alternatives to this issue ?

Comment: What's your max instance? Did you try your container locally?

Comment: as in the image above my maximum instance is 20, but my specification is 80 per container so logically this service sould be able to handle 1600 request maximum right, but i do know that there is cold start for container initialization, so i tried to make the minimum instance to 10, but it doesn't make any difference

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes i have tried it locally and there is no problem in handling 1000 concurrent request

Comment: Here is the [troubleshooting guide of a cloud run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/local-troubleshooting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was vpc connector, because our database is connected using tcp/ip and we have to whitelist a public ip to be able to access it securely and that is why we are using vpc, so we are using mikrotik to bind our ip instead of using vpc connector. and the gcr service can finally handle 10000 request.